# jsonp parse to XML

Tags: ajax, xml, cordova, blackberry

I'm having the following problem.

I'm developing an app with `Phonegap`, and I have some trouble with the `AJAX` call on Blackberry.
When I call the ajax service with `datatype = 'xml'`, it works fine on Windows Phone, and Android but failed on Blackberry.

This is the code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: requestedUrl,
                dataType: 'xml',
                timeout: this.timeout,
                beforeSend: _.bind(this.beforeSendCallback, this),
                success: _.bind(this.internalSuccessCallback, this),
                error: _.bind(this.internalErrorCallback, this),
                headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
            })
```

I read on others post, that you cannot do an`XMLHttpRequest` to an external domain, which is the error that Blackberry shows (but I don't understand why it works on the other two platforms.) So I try to change the dataType to 'jsonp', but a syntaxError shows up. I tried with `jsonp text xml`, but for some reason it does not and returns the same

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Looking, the response of the WS, it gave me back a valid `XML`. So the question is, 
How can I use that XML if I'm making the call with `jsonp`?

EDIT:

Actually, the problem was that the "origin" header was "local:\" (my app), so BB was blocking the content of the response.
The solution was to add that domain to my `config.xml`, like this:

```
<access uri="local:///" subdomains="true" />
```

Unlikely Android and Windows Phone, in the `config.xml` you have to set access to the domains with uri, not origin and the * wildcard is not allowed with XmlHttpRequest (XHR) on BlackBerry 10.

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Comment: @dr_dev No, I tried everything, but I can't make BB accept the XML. The temporary (and at this point permanent) solution, is to use a proxy to make the ajax calls (I use this one  [link](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) )